# Not able to do pip install saspy

Tags: python, pip, sas, jupyter, saspy

I am using jupyter notebook and tried to run pip install saspy and i am getting the following error.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement saspy
ERROR: No matching distribution found for saspy

Note: I have the python version 3.9.6 and sas version 9.4 in my machine.

Can you please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Did you try inside your notebook `%conda install saspy`?

Comment: Did not work. Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed

Comment: If you weren't trying with pip in the notebook already, can you try `%pip install saspy` in a notebook cell?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `python3 -m pip install saspy`. I have the same issue on my machine and this workaround works for me

Comment: File "<ipython-input-4-254ece1126b9>", line 1
    python3 -m pip install saspy
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

For Jupyter, you need to install `sas_kernel`.  From the Conda prompt, `pip install sas_kernel`.

See [this blog post by SAS](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Installing-SASPy-Kernel-for-Jupyter-Notebooks-and-Jupyter-Lab/ta-p/464873) for more specifics.

If you still have difficulty, it's recommended to post in the SASPy github page ([here](https://github.com/sassoftware/saspy/issues)) as the developers are very responsive.